# Ajax and bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make an ajax call to delete a user making use of a bootstrap modal.
The modal is used for confirmation purposes and it is the following.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="deleteModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<h3 id="myModalLabel">Delete user</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>You are about to delete this user. Are you sure that you want to continue?</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button id="confirm" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
<button id="cancel" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">No, leave</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Then I am using the following javascript to process the user input

```
    $('a#delete').click(function(e){
        var anchor = this;
        $('#deleteModal').modal('show');
        $('button#confirm').click(function(e){
            $('#deleteModal').modal('hide');
            $.ajax({
                url: $(anchor).attr('href'),
                success:function(result){
                    $(anchor).closest('tr').addClass("error");
                    $(anchor).closest('tr').delay(2000).fadeOut();
              }});
        });
        return false;
    });
```

The link that user has to click is like this

```
<a id="delete" href="/admin/edit/user/delete/30" class="btn btn-danger" user="30"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a>
```

It works but I noticed that something weird happens. If I click to delete one user and I choose to cancel the action from the modal and then I choose to delete another user confirming the action, both users are deleted.

I think that the rule I have declared still applies in the objects that have been clicked during a session. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is because of the way in which you are registering the `click` event on `button#confirm`. Every time you click on the delete button you are registering a new click event handler to the modal dialog's confirm button.

Problem with you approach is [demonstrated here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YYtqq/2/).

It can be fixed by splitting the logic into two parts

```
$('button#confirm').click(function(e){
    $('#deleteModal').modal('hide');
    $.ajax({
        url: $('#deleteModal').attr('href'),
        success:function(result){
            $(anchor).closest('tr').addClass("error");
            $(anchor).closest('tr').delay(2000).fadeOut();
      }});
});

$('a#delete').click(function(e){
    var anchor = this;
    $('#deleteModal').modal('show').attr('href', $(anchor).attr('href'));
    return false;
});
```

Here we registers the `confirm` click event only once at the page loading, but when the delete button is clicked we pass a context information to the confirmation modal via the `user` attribute. In the confirm callback we use this context information to determine which user has to be deleted.

You can test it in the [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YYtqq/3/).

Comment: This fixes the issue but `$(anchor)` is not available in `$('button#confirm').click(function(e)`.

Comment: Why do you want the `anchor` in the confirm callback? If you require the anchor then the following query should solve it `var anchor = $('a#delete[href="' + $('#deleteModal').attr('href') + '"]');`

Answer (score 0):

When a user clicks a link it's submitted despite of the dialog button clicked. You need to prevent the default behavior: `e.preventDefault();`

```
  $('a#delete').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var anchor = this;
    $('#deleteModal').modal('show');
    $('button#confirm').click(function(e){
        $('#deleteModal').modal('hide');
        $.ajax({
            url: $(anchor).attr('href'),
            success:function(result){
                $(anchor).closest('tr').addClass("error");
                $(anchor).closest('tr').delay(2000).fadeOut();
          }});
    });
    return false;
});
```

A different way to do this is not to put the href value to the links. You already have user attribute so it's some kind of duplication:

```
<a id="delete" class="btn btn-danger" user="30"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</a>
```

and js:

```
 $('a#delete').click(function(e){
    var anchor = this;
    var del_link = '/admin/edit/user/delete/' + $(anchor).attr('user');
    $('#deleteModal').modal('show');
    $('button#confirm').click(function(e){
        $('#deleteModal').modal('hide');
        $.ajax({
            url: del_link,
            success:function(result){
                $(anchor).closest('tr').addClass("error");
                $(anchor).closest('tr').delay(2000).fadeOut();
          }});
    });
    return false;
});
```

Do you use the same `delete` id for all delete links?

Answer (score 0):

unbind your click event with .unbind() or do .one() to you click event make sure it only excute once.

```
$('a#delete').one('click', function(e) {
```

or

```
$('a#delete').unbind().live('click', function(e) {
```